# Multi threaded server send function

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, server

I got this multi threaded server code and it works but when I type something to send to the client its not sending it the send function only work if I send the data string
anyone knows what's the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket, threading

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, ip, port, clientsocket):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.csocket = clientsocket
        print "[+] New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)

    def run(self):    
        print "Connection from : "+ip+":"+str(port)

        clientsock.send("Welcome to the server ")

        data = "dummydata"

        while len(data):
            data = self.csocket.recv(2048)
            print "Client(%s:%s) sent : %s"%(self.ip, str(self.port), data)

            userInput = raw_input(">")
            self.csocket.send(userInput)

        print "Client at "+self.ip+" disconnected..."

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 4444

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

tcpsock.bind((host, port))

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(4)
    print "nListening for incoming connections..."
    (clientsock, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()

    #pass clientsock to the ClientThread thread object being created
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port, clientsock)
    newthread.start()
```

Comment: `listen()` only needs to be called once. You can move it up by the `bind()`.

Comment: Also, can you explain what "the send function only work if I send the data string" means?

Comment: it means when i use self.csocket.send(data) instead of self.csocket.send(userInput) it sends what the client sended

Comment: How did you establish that the data wasn't sent? Be as precise as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can see at least one thing that will prevent this from working as intended:

```
def run(self):    
    print "Connection from : "+ip+":"+str(port)

    clientsock.send("Welcome to the server ")
```

`clientsock` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is don't try to reinvent the wheel (unless you want to understand how the wheel works). There's already the built-in [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) but that is *synchronous*, meaning each request must be completed before the next request can be started.

There are already very easy to use implementations of *asynchronous* (non-blocking) TCP servers out there. If you want something that doesn't require you to learn a framework and just runs out-of-the-box, I suggest [simpleTCP](http://gragas.github.io/simpletcp). Here's an example of an echo server:

```
from simpletcp.tcpserver import TCPServer

def echo(ip, queue, data):
    queue.put(data)

server = TCPServer("localhost", 5000, echo)
server.run()
```

And here's an example of a client connecting to it:

```
from simpletcp.clientsocket import ClientSocket

s1 = ClientSocket("localhost", 5000)
response = s1.send("Hello, World!")
```